# working with css Rules using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am finding css Rules and then changing it's style and i am done with it 
but i don't know why i am getting this error

```
TypeError: sh[i] is undefined
if ("undefined"!==sh[i].cssRules)
```

my code is here

```
window.onload = function() {
        var sh = document.styleSheets;
        for (var i = 1; i <= sh.length; i++) {
            if (sh[i].cssRules)
                rule = sh[i].cssRules;
            else if (sh[i].rules)
                rule = sh[i].rules;
            for (var j = 0; j < rule.length; j++) {
                var sel = rule[j].selectorText;
                if (sel == ".test") {
                    var R = rule[j].style;
                    R.color = "red";
                }
            }
        }
        var C = document.createElement("div");
        C.className = "test";
        C.innerHTML = "test";
        var E = document.getElementById("div1");
        E.appendChild(C);
    }
```

i am finding all css that has been load to page and then find rule that i want to change.

if you have any question please ask me

Comment: i got the problem. so no need to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved :**

problem was at this line

```
for (var i = 1; i <= sh.length; i++) {
```

repalced `<=` withi `<`